# How to build a dataframe from scratch while filling in missing data? (details included in question)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like the following (Name of the first dataframe(image below) is `relevantdata` in the code):

[image]

I want the dataframe to be transformed to the following format:

[image]

Essentially, I want to get the relevant confirmed number for each Key for all the dates that are available in the dataframe. If a particular date is not available for a Key, we make that value to be zero.

Currently my code is as follows (A try/except block is used as some Keys don't have the the whole range of dates, hence a Keyerror occurs the first time you refer to that date using `countrydata.at[date,'Confirmed']` for the respective Key, hence the `except` block will make an entry of zero into the dictionary for that date):

```
relevantdata = pandas.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-covid-19/data/master/output/data_minimal.csv')
dates = relevantdata['Date'].unique().tolist()
covidcountries = relevantdata['Key'].unique().tolist()
data = dict()
data['Country'] = covidcountries
confirmeddata = relevantdata[['Date','Key','Confirmed']]

for country in covidcountries:
    for date in dates:
        countrydata = confirmeddata.loc[lambda confirmeddata: confirmeddata['Key'] == country].set_index('Date')
        try:
            if (date in data.keys()) == False:
                data[date] = list()
                data[date].append(countrydata.at[date,'Confirmed'])
            else:
                data[date].append(countrydata.at[date,'Confirmed'])
        except:
            if (date in data.keys()) == False:
                data[date].append(0)
            else:
                data[date].append(0)
finaldf = pandas.DataFrame(data = data)
```

While the above code accomplished what I want in getting the dataframe in the format I require, it is way too slow, having to loop through every key and date. I want to know if there is a better and faster method to doing the same without having to use a nested for loop. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: `df.pivot('Key', 'Date', 'Confirmed')`?

Comment: Thanks. I can use this.